# Find vba code from an excel file did not open

Tags: vba, excel, xlsm

I have my code in an excel file but the problem that I can't open this file. What can I do in this case?
It's in 100% and I wait and it doesn't like to be opened.
[image]

[image]

Comment: Hold the SHIFT key when you open the workbook to prevent code from running.

Comment: try this http://www.jkp-ads.com/articles/preventopenevent.asp

Comment: Emna, this kind of question is off-topic for this website. You might want to consider deleting this post here and re-posting it instead on [SuperUser](https://meta.superuser.com/questions/4836/what-is-the-difference-between-super-user-and-stack-overflow) again. In the meantime you might want to try this: https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Repair-a-corrupted-workbook-153a45f4-6cab-44b1-93ca-801ddcd4ea53 or try opening the file with something other than Excel. For example: http://www.libreoffice.org/

Comment: Bonne chance et n'hésites pas à revenir si t'as une question de programmation.

Comment: I tested all these methods but it remains the same problem

Comment: You could try opening it on a machine that is not connected to your work network and not connected to the internet. In fact, not connected to anything at all. This would eliminate the possibility that something in the spreadsheet is trying to connect to a database and hanging - or something along those lines.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not really sure if this is going to help. But I was unable to post this "picture" in a comment. Hence, I am posting it as a possible solution to your problem:

[image]

1. Open Excel and go to the VBE (Developer Tab --> Macros)
2. Open the `Immdediate Window` in the VBE
3. Type in the command as given below (make sure to change the path and file name as necessary) and confirm by pressing return.

The file should now open in `read only` mode and a small window should notify you that Excel attempted to repair the file while opening it.

```
Workbooks.Open FileName:="C:\tmp\ProblematicFile.xlsm", UpdateLinks:=False, ReadOnly:=True, CorruptLoad:=xlRepairFile
```

Comment: Thanks, but always the same problem: Excel (Not Responding)

Comment: Did you try to open the file with [LibreOffice](https://de.libreoffice.org/download/portable-versions/) (no installation necessary)? If you want you can also send me the file and I'll have a look. My email is in my profile.